# Javascript event listeners to trigger php code or vice versa?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

MY CODE:

```
<section class="content">
    <h2 class="heading">Milestones Navigation</h2>
    <div style="width: 100%;">

    <button style="width: 16%;" id="0-3m">0-3M</button>
    <button style="width: 16%;" id="3-6m">3-6M</button>
    <button style="width: 16%;" id="6-9m">6-9M</button>
    <button style="width: 16%;" id="9-12m">9-12M</button>
    <button style="width: 16%;" id="12-18m">12-18M</button>
    <button style="width: 16%;" id="18Mup">18M+</button>

    </div>
</section>
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($db_conn, $m);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $age = $row['age'];
    $cat = $row['category'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $desc = $row['description'];
    ?>
    <section class="content">
        <h2 class="heading" style="border:none;">
            <div>
                <div style=" float:left; text-align: left; font-family: 'Yu Gothic Medium',sans-serif; border-bottom: solid thin lightgray;">
                    <small><strong><?php echo $title; ?></strong></small>
                </div>

            </div>
        </h2>
        <br><br>
        <div>
            <div style="font-family: 'Droid Sans',sans-serif; margin-top: 5%; display: inline; width: 50%;">
                <?php echo $desc; ?>
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline; text-align: right; width: 30%; float:right; font-family: 'Yu Gothic Medium',sans-serif; text-transform: capitalize">
                <small><?php echo $age .' | ' . $cat; ?></small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php
}
?>
```

MY QUESTION:

I want each button to correspond to a certain range of ages, (Pressing the 0-3M button will display only those sections that have $age equal to 00M, 01M, 02M, and 03M). I'm not sure how to pull that data as I'm using a loop to pull my section content from an sql database. I'm looking for the correct way to do this. Should I add an additional column in my database with the age-range? (For example, column name is Range and then pull it into a variable to check?) Then use that to trigger javascript? Or should I run an if statement to check for the range? I've tried looking it up but I don't really see any answers for what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are already pulling in the data with your `while` loop, and it is already categorized by month, why not add each record to its own array? You could have an array `$newborn`, `$less_than_one`, `$toddler`, etc. checked by an `if` or `switch` statement in the loop: `if  ($row['age'] < 4) { $newborn[] = $row}`

Comment: The ages are set up like "03M" , "02-04M", etc. They're not integers, would this still work?

Comment: No, they should be integers to do a math operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend each section an additional class based on its range. You can add the Range field in the database or use PHP code to determine the range - something like this:

```
switch($row['age']) {
    case '00M':
    case '01M':
    case '02M':
    case '03M':
        $range = 'age3m';
    // ...
    // Fill in the other ranges here
    // ...
    default:
        $range = 'age18m';
}
```

Once this is done, you can add `$range` as a class on the section. Then use javascript to show/hide based on the class of the button that is pressed.

Comment: So I added the $range to the sql database and pulled it into the class name. How would I use the javascript? I'm not familiar with switch statements at all, so I'm not sure how to implement the javascript. Do you have an example?

Comment: If you are using JQuery, you can do something like this: `<button id="0-3m" onclick="$('.content').hide(); $('.age3m').show();">0-3M</button>` If you aren't, then something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13367834/1352293).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, PHP is a scripting language that runs on the server. On the other hand, JavaScript is a scripting language that runs on the client (browser).

When JavaScript "start its work", PHP already have completed and the information was sent to the client.

PHP can't call any trigger in JavaScript and vice-versa. However, JavaScript can do an AJAX call which can call a PHP script (or a web service) and PHP can write/echo any javascript code (but I don't recommend this approach).

To filter the data, there's two solutions.

Do an AJAX call passing the chosen range.

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click' , function(event) {
    var id = this.id;
    /** ajax call and javascript process **/
});
```

Or render all table and show the range that has been chosen. The second option will also make use of an event listener.